# Select first row of row_number() only if row number 2 has condition x?

Tags: sql-server

I need to select the first row of a row_number view only if the second row has a specific condition.

Now, how do I check the condition of the rows?

I might get this view:

```
row_num   value
1          1
2          1
```

But, I need only the first row, if it looks like this:

```
row_num   value
1          1
2          2
```

So, I guess what I need is something like:

"select the first row when the value in the second row is 2"

How to do that?

Comment: You need cursor for this.

Comment: Is that all the columns the view has? Also, what do you want to happen when the value for `row_number` 2 *isn't* 2?

Comment: @ aakashm no, there are more colums, but these are basically the only ones that i need. also, "value" can only be 1 or 0 (sorry, mistyped in the opening post), as its a bit value. @ vittore: care to explain? i looked some tutorials up, but i dont understand how this can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but how about this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
yourView v1
LEFT JOIN yourView v2 ON v1.row_num = v2.row_num -1
WHERE 
MOD(v1.row_num, 2) != 0
AND v2.value = 2
```

With the `MOD(v1.row_num, 2) != 0` you get only the rows where row_num is odd, because I understood your question like this:

```
table
-----
type | row_num | value
a      1         x
b      2         y
a      3         z
b      4         xx
```

You need only the rows of type a and only if the value of the corresponding b row is 2.

Is this right?

Comment: hm, no i guess. i'm counting the first row depending on the second row. later i also need to count the second and third row. the condition is the value of the second row. i already "filtered" by the first row, so it will always have the desired value. the rows will be filtered by date ultimately.

Comment: Then I suggest you provide more sample data than 2 rows and explain more clearly what you're after. Actually I have no clue...